# SWIFT 5 language localization in File.Strings does not work for me

Tags: swift, localization

I try to code my first app but I have some problems to get the localization running.

I got all these files in, but it simply happens nothing. (all the changes I made in the main.Storyboard files are fine). But I need to change some variables as well.

[Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tdtH.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyOz3.jpg)

```
if editTaskMode == 0 {
    let saveTest = NSLocalizedString("Save", comment: "Save")
    takeOverButton.setTitle(saveTest, for: .normal)
} else if editTaskMode == 1 {
    takeOverButton.setTitle("Save changes", for: .normal)
    loadTask()
}
```

So why does the File.strings not show up in my broswer from XCode? And why it doesn't exchange the String "Save" with "Speichern"?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLzKe.jpg)

```
/* 
  File.strings
  TheGame2

  Created by Stefan Wahrendorff on 18.03.20.
  Copyright © 2020 Stefan Wahrendorff. All rights reserved.
*/
"Save" = "Speichern";
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dHjf.jpg)

Comment: Use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocalizedstringfromtable?language=objc instead and use the table `"File"`, which is the name of your localizable file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a String File, and localized the words

Use:

```
extension String {

   func localized() -> String {
      return localized(withComment: "")
   }

   func localized(withComment: String) -> String {
      var localized = Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: self, value: withComment, table: "Default")
      if localized == self {
        localized = Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: self, value: withComment, table: nil)
      }
      return localized
   }
}
```

and just call:

```
"Save".localized()
```

Comment: OK thanks! But can u explain me why it doesnt work like in a lot of tutorials anymore? like this tutorial as a reference ? https://www.raywenderlich.com/250-internationalizing-your-ios-app-getting-started

Comment: Ok now it works... the probblem is, that XCODE is creating a file with a the name File.Strings instead of Localizable.Strings . Just rename the .Strings and everything si working like a charm!

Comment: in this code the file name is Default, you can name it as you want, Localizable, File etc.